# Model Framework for Actionscript 3.0

Tags: model-view-controller, actionscript, frameworks, model

What is Model Framework for Actionscript 3.0?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? There a lot of different frameworks for ActionScript 3 out there, many of which are based on MVC. Are you asking for a recommendation or about a specific framework?

Comment: Yes, actually I want to know that which framework is most useful and what all developers recommend to use.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using the spring actionscript framework to create my last flash application. It works great and injects the power of spring into flash. You only need to create an xml file declaring all the classes (& relationships) that will be injected in your swf. Any change to the xml file doesn't require any recompile which is great.

You can find more info about it [on this site](http://www.pranaframework.org/).

It also an extension to work with the MVC pattern.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The best MVC lib for as3 out there is [Robot Legs](http://www.robotlegs.org)

Answer (score 1):

I'd never done any proper MVC programming from scratch. But I've used [RobotLegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/) with much success - it is well written, easy to pickup and easy to scale. The community is also active, and the developers do a good job of answering questions on the forums (I've never had to bother registering on the forums to post a question, I've always successfully searched the community forums).

Great introductory tutorials:

1. [Part 1: Context and Mediators](http://www.developria.com/2010/06/an-introduction-to-robotlegs-a.html)
2. [Part 2: Models](http://www.developria.com/2010/06/an-introduction-to-robotlegs-a-1.html)
3. [Part 3: Services](http://www.developria.com/2010/06/an-introduction-to-robotlegs-a-2.html)

Answer (score 0):

Robotlegs: The most easy to use MVC framework to use with great community support and for Medium-Large scale apps